# Why does my Football Manager 12 screen turn black when I start a match?

Tags: football-manager-2012

Sometimes, when I start a match on FM 12, the screen will turn totally black, and I can do nothing but shut the game and start again. Those familiar with FM 12 will know now that the cursor changes from an arrow to a hand on clickable items, and this still happens when I move the cursor around the black screen. I am using Windows Vista and the game is running on Steam. Why is this happening and how do I fix it?

Comment: Have you tried to run the program as an Administrator?

Comment: Also, you could try this link : http://www.neoseeker.com/forums/55050/t1693851-problem/